# TypeScript: Imported Module Not Compiling

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have a simple TypeScript file that imports a local TypeScript module. Everything links fine when I compile it, but the compiled JavaScript file is trying to `require` my TypeScript module which I'm importing, instead of compiling it.

Here's an example of my file layout:

**module.ts**

```
declare module "MyModule" {
  export var name: string;
}
```

**test.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../../src/module.ts"/>

import MyModule = require('MyModule');

var myName = MyModule.name;
myName = 'Nick';

console.log(myName);
```

I attempt to compile it like so:

`ntsc mockup.ts` and also tried (with the same results) `ntsc mockup.ts --module commonjs`

It compiles to this:

**test.js**

```
/// <reference path="../../src/modern/needle.ts"/>
"use strict";
var MyModule = require('MyModule');
var myName = MyModule.name;
myName = 'Nick';
console.log(myName);
```

It also attempts to compile `module.ts` but the file that comes from it is completely empty. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong? The line `var MyModule = require('MyModule');` clearly isn't correct (the file wrong run because of it). I suspect something might be wrong with my module file, especially since it's not compiling correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to declare an existing non-TypeScript module called `MyModule`, or write your own module with that name?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh I'm trying to write my own module in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file layout should look something like this:

***test.ts***

```
import mod = require('./MyModule');

console.log(mod.name);
```

***MyModule.ts***

```
export var name = 'Hello, world!';
```

Run `tsc --module commonjs test.ts` to compile, then `node test.js` to execute.

Comment: So `declare module "..." {}` wrapper is not the way to go?

Comment: That does something entirely different from what you think it does

Answer (score 1):

> It also attempts to compile module.ts but the file that comes from it is completely empty

Because `module.ts` only has *declarations*. Declarations are just hints to the compiler and will not do any actual JavaScript emit.